# Connecting to SQLite Database Fails

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I am attempting to access my SQLite3 database in a Java Applet. When I run my code to connect to the database I get this error **No suitable driver found for a.db**, how can I fix it?

Now I am not entirely sure I have actually installed the correct driver...I will tell you what I have done & could you tell me what else I need to do to make Eclipse IDE find the SQLitejdbc driver:

> - BK info: On windows 7, using Eclipse Helios Java
> - I have a SQLite3 database created in python & I want to read it in my Java Applet
> - I have downloaded the file sqlitejdbc-V056.jar from http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/
> - Then I copied & pasted the above file to the paths C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib & C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext
> - Run the following code in a Java Applet & get an exception thrown with the text: **"No suitable driver found for a.db"**

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("a.db"); // exception thrown here
```

Any information would be really helpful. Do I need to import the driver into my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:a.db");
```