# SEVERE: null java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, sqlite, jtable, sqlexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting to SQLite Database Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917855/connecting-to-sqlite-database-fails)

I'm a beginner to Java

When I want to get output from SQLite to `JTable` in GUI interface, I get this exception :

> SEVERE: null
>       java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\Amr\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project\BillsDataBase.sqlite
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)  at
>   NewClass.(NewClass.java:22)     at
>   NewClass$5.run(NewClass.java:342)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Code:

```
public class NewClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public NewClass() {     
        initComponents(); 
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Amr\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project\\BillsDataBase.sqlite");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void Update_table(){
        try {
            String sql ="SELECT Amount, Type,Invoice FROM BillsDataBase";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            Table_Bills.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

In rest, there is a table which is called `Table_Bills`

Comment: From the exception, it looks like you don't have the sqlite jdbc driver in your classpath when you run the program.  Have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/

Answer (score 1):

Did you successfully accomplish:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```